# defining a hash set with a compare function

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a very simple task of defining a new type of hash set which has a compare function as well.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <ext/hash_set>
#include <hash_set>
#include <functional>
#include <hash_compare>
typedef __gnu_cxx::hash_set<int, hash_compare<int, less<int> > > hashcomp;

int main(int argc, char *  const argv[]) {

}
```

Error: hash_compare is not defined   (line 7)
Error: expected unqualified-id before ">" token    (line 7)
Error: template argument 2 is invalid.     (line 7)

Comment: @Pegah: Why don't you post error messages with line number... and also mention which line corresponds to which piece of code...

Comment: Is a space before :: intentional?

Comment: @Alexei Sholik the space is not intentional. deleted it. still same errors.

Comment: @Nawaz I did not understand what you mean by: "which line corresponds to which piece of code"

Comment: @Pegah: See the error message clearly says `Error: hash_compare is not defined`. What else do you want?

Comment: @Nawaz Dear Nawaz, thanks for your help already. I tried to find out how to define the hash_compare by searching the web. I changed the code as you see up there. errors are quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the error, I guess you haven't included `<functional>` as you're using `std::less<int>` in your code. I'm assuming that `less<int>` in your code is actually `std::less<int>`.

EDIT:

The error message clearly says

> Error: hash_compare is not defined.

What else do you want? Include the header file which defines `hash_compare`.

Comment: @Nawaz I added: #include <functional> but still the same error.

Comment: @Pegah: Use `std::less<int>` instead of `less<int>`.

Comment: @Nawaz using namespace std;
#include <hash_set>
#include <functional>
typedef __gnu_cxx ::hash_set<int, hash_compare<int, std::less<int> now it is like this, but still the same error.

Comment: @Nawaz I deleted every thing, now I have only an empty main(). I have three errors from the line that I am defining hashnew

Comment: @Nawaz 1) Error: hash_compare is not defined 2) Error: Error: expected unqualified-id before »>« token 3) Error: template argument 2 is not valid.

Comment: using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <ext/hash_set>
#include <ext/hash_map>
#include <hash_set>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
typedef __gnu_cxx ::hash_set<int> intset;
typedef __gnu_cxx ::hash_map<int, char*> intmap;
typedef __gnu_cxx ::hash_set<int, hash_compare<int, less<int> > > hashcomp;
#pragma mark CLASS DEFINITIONS

int main(int argc, char *  const argv[]) {

}

Comment: @Pegah: You think I will spend time understanding this code which you copy-pasted in the comment? You think I'm a compiler?

Comment: It is nothing! it is just lots of include. and the main is empty.

Comment: @Nawaz It is shorter! using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <ext/hash_set>
#include <hash_set>
#include <functional>
typedef __gnu_cxx ::hash_set<int, hash_compare<int, less<int> > > hashcomp;

int main(int argc, char *  const argv[]) {

}

Comment: @Pegah: Whatever that is, do you think that is readable enough? Why don't you post this in your question itself?

Comment: @Pegah: So you will not understand? You still think I'm a compiler?

Comment: I am really Sorry! i did not think about it.

Comment: @Nawaz I added hash_compare header file. still the same three errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are contradictory.  A hash table has a random order, by definition.

Comment: which means that it is not possible to sort a hash_set?

Comment: No.  The hash management imposes its own order (which is not anything you'ld be likely to want).